# How to call custom slider from backend to frontend dynamically in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, slider, dynamic

I have created a custom module in backend for uploading image slider in homepage, but I am not able to call in homepage?(frontend).
I don't know where I am making mistake.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$modelCollection = $objectManager->get('Amy\Homebanner\Model\Grid')->getCollection();
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($modelCollection->getData());
  echo "</pre>";
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<div class="ves-slideshow container">
<div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">

    <div class="ves-slider">

     <?php foreach ($modelCollection as $_model) { ?>
        <?php if ($_model->getIsActive() == '0' && $_model->getPageSelection() == '1') { ?>
                <li <?php if ($_model->getUrl() != '') { ?> onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $_model->getUrl() ?>'" <?php } ?>>

        <?php if ($deviceDetect->isMobile()) { ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $_model->getImageMobile() ?>" alt="<?php echo $_model['alternate_text'] ?>" title="<?php echo $_model['alternate_text'] ?>" />

        <?php }else{ ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $_model->getImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $_model['alternate_text'] ?>" title="<?php echo $_model['alternate_text'] ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When the status is enabled the homepage shows blank, while the status is disabled the homepage is showing but the slider is not showing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, it is not module status. It is each field status $_model->getIsActive() == '0'

Comment: Do you have helper? if so remove object manager and get the collection by applying filter using DI

Comment: How did you added this phtml to home page?? via xml or cms?

Comment: I am using theme. so i override the theme and applied in theme homepage.

Comment: Okay i will try it, and let you know..

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code

1. You Should not use object manager directly in you files.
2. You should not call model directly for collection than create a Repository class for you module , create a getlist Method and filter collection using search criteria .
3. Rather than getting the full collection filter the collection before by checking IsActive == 1
4. Use [ViewModel](https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2) rather than posting code in you PHTML

   Regarding the above code issue try

> ```
>    $modelCollection = $objectManager->get('Amy\Homebanner\Model\Grid');
>     $modelCollection ->getCollection()
>         ->addFieldToSelect('*')
>         ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1');
>     if ($modelCollection->getSize() > 0) {//show slider?>
> ```

if you are still facing the issue switch to developer mode and in file '\app\bootstrap.php'  uncomment the following line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Your error will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Get collection using helper **Data.php**

Place Data.php in the below path

> app/code/Amy/Homebanner/Helper/Data.php

then add the below code to get the collection by filter **i.e., is_active = '0' and page_selection = '1'** so

```
<?php
namespace Amy\Homebanner\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
     \Amy\Homebanner\Model\GridFactory $collection
    ) {
       $this->collection = $collection;
     }

    public function getCollection()
    {
       $dataCollection = $this->collection->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array(
        'eq' => '0'
    ))->addFieldToFilter('page_selection', array(
        'eq' => '1'
    ));
       return $dataCollection;
     }
}
```

then call this in your phtml

```
$data = $this->helper('Amy\Homebanner\Helper\Data')->getCollection();
```

then foreach to print the collection as you require

```
foreach($data as $items){
   echo $items->getIsActive();
}
```

> NOTE : Object Manager shouldn't used anywhere since because it will create object each time when the file load. So it consume loads of memory and time. Site will literally slow down. Best practice to go for DI.

In addition to above answer, enable developer mode check the issue.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Hope it helps .